# Mark up text as instance segmentation or semantic segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have data with a page of handwriting and I want to segment each word individually. If I mark each word for semantic segmentation, then the model will impose a segmentation mask on each word separately, or do I need to mark up instance segmentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

this can be of your help.

https://www.kaggle.com/code/dmitryyemelyanov/receipt-ocr-part-1-image-segmentation-by-opencv

you need to further extend it for words.

Comment: Instead of simply posting a code link, try to explain what this code does and how could it be extended.